# How can I wrap an arbitrary piece of text in an indented block in Sublime Text 3 using a keybinding?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Let's say I have:

```
doSomeAction()
```

and I want to wrap it in some arbitrary text, such that the original text is indented:

```
if myValue
  doSomeAction()
end
```

Ideally I'd like to highlight my line, press some keybinding, and have the original text indented, and my cursor on what becomes the first line, where I'd type the `if myValue` (or whatever).

I realize this depends on the programming language I'm in, mostly regarding what comes *after* the original line. In Ruby, I need `end`, in Javascript, I need `}`, and in Coffeescript, I need nothing :-) I figure if it's left blank, such that I can press `tab` to get to that spot, I can type what's needed myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can **create a snippet** for that purpose. Example:

```xml
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[
${1:if condition}
    $SELECTION${3}
${2:end}
${4}
]]></content>
</snippet>
```

**Imporant note:** Stackoverflows shows this text with spaces but remember to use tabs for indentations in snippets: see Tyler edit and comments at the bottom of this answer.

As you can see it can have multipe parts starting with `$` delimiting positions, you can navigate all parts using `tab`, this allows you easily change the content of the condition or to add extra content inside. You can easily change the structure, add or remove parts, content, change default values, etc.

---

## RESULT:

[image: Sublime wrap snippet]

---

### ¿How to create the snippet?

Use menu *Tools > new Snippet*, then put the given file content in the new file. Save it inside sublime Packages/User with the (example) filename *wrap.sublime-snippet*. Usually Packages/User is the default folder showed, and usually Packages folder is opened via menu *Preferences>Browse Packages*.

### ¿How to add the key-binding?

Go to menu *Preferences > Key Bindings-user* and add your keybinding inside the global array, use a free key combination you like and save the file. If you dont have any other user key-bindings this file content should be something like this (remember to use the name you give to the snippet):

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+z"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"name": "Packages/User/wrap.sublime-snippet"}}   
]
```

EDIT: Always use a tab for indentation in snippets as [recommended by Sublime Text help](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/snippets.html):

> When writing a snippet that contains indentation, always use tabs. The
>   tabs will be transformed into spaces when the snippet is inserted if
>   the option translateTabsToSpaces is set to true.

Comment: Awesome! All parts of this are exactly what I wanted! I love how the snippet has 4 placeholders to I can tab to the wrap condition, end text, back to the middle, and then after. This answer is spectacular too, showing me the result and the exact instructions for making the snippet and keybinding. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I was a little premature in calling the solution perfect. I tried it on a multi-line segment, and the first line gets indented properly, but the subsequent lines gets indented multiple times. After trying it in a few more places, Sublime sometimes gets it right and sometimes not. This is probably an issue with sublime, not your solution.

Comment: Rats. I used a tab for snippet indentation, but Stackoverflow converted it back to spaces. I imagine you did the same thing!

Comment: Actually I have only tried using spaces, now I see tabs should be used to solve indentation problems. Thanks for your edit.

Comment: In addition, remember to accept the answer if it solved your problem.